# vbscript take user input option to run different command

Tags: vbscript

I already have a script that is working in with one click, first unzip and second execute the setup.

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("7z.exe x temp.7z")
wscript.sleep (3000)
objShell.Run("/temp/setup1.exe")
```

Now I need to modify the script to have different setup take from user input

I have setup1.exe, setup2.exe, setup3.exe, it depend user select the option 1,2 or 3 but the unzip command is must and one time.

I have script take user input and run command with it but not meet the requirement, please help.

```
strInput = InputBox("prompt")
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "cmd /K net user " & strInput & "" 
Set oShell = Nothing
```

Comment: What about it does not meet the requirement? Also what are you expecting to happen with `oShell.Run "cmd /K net user " & strInput & ""`?

Comment: Windows comes with a setup program that you can use and do everything you want via a wizard. Type `iexpress` in Run (Winkey + R) and follow the wizard.

Comment: That is a example, I don't want to net user.

The strInput will take from user input from the windows prompt, 1,2,3,4

The first unzip command will run regardless but second command will depend what user input like if user input 1 then run this line if user input 2 then run this line, I have 4 to 5 if statement.

Comment: That problem not presented by current question..how `if` used in your code? etc..please update your question!..

Answer (score 0):

The Elseif statement for different user input result help to solve the problem, thank you all.